# Bluetooth Connection to Fora D15B from Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, health-monitoring

I am working on android app which connects to FORA D15b (2-in-1 Blood pressure/glucose monitor).

I have tried many combination for this purpose but till now none has worked.

Here is what i tried.

```
BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(BhMacID);
String deviceName = device.getName();
Log.v("BP", "Device : " + deviceName);
try {
  Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });
  socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, Integer.valueOf(1));
  // socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(HS_UUID));
  // socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(HS_UUID));
 socket.connect();
 Log.v("BP", "Connected");
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have created socket using three different ways both none works given below exception

*java.io.IOException: Connection refused at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connectNative(Native Method)*

I have also tried an android app from google play app myFitnessCompanion https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myfitnesscompanion 

which works fine on my phone.

Please help, will be great if someone can help how does exactly the myFitnessCompanion  connects to FORA D15b.

-Pramod

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHealth.html, this is since 14 however

Comment: you may also need to pair device before you start communication

Comment: The device is paired before doing this. Good thing is that i am able to connect to device using above mentioned code first time but even after is close the socket i get the IOException every time.

One workaround I found for this is to restart FORA device before a new connection request.